# Check if socket listen backlog queue is empty

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

Is there any way to check if there are no pending connection requests to the server?

In my case, I have this code, from C:

```
listen(mysocket, 3);
//while(no pending connections) do this
int consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
```

And what I need, is that while there are no pending connections, do something else, instead of getting stuck waiting, by calling accept().

Comment: thought about spawning a new thread and doing your "something else" and the main thread waiting on the `accept()` ?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, because as soon as a client requests to connect, the "something else" no longer needs to be executed. Hence why I was hoping there is an simpler way...

Comment: Why not kill the thread as soon as the client connects?

Comment: Yeah, I realized it might be the best solution, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a socket in non-blocking mode with [`fcntl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK);
```

After that, a call to [`accept(sockfd)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) will either immediately return a newly accepted connection or immediately fail with `EWOULDBLOCK` which you can use to decide to do “something else”.

Another option would be to use [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), maybe with a finite timeout, to gain finer grained control over blocking.

Comment: If `accept()` fails with `EWOULDBLOCK` could you call `accept()` again on the same `sockfd` or do you need to go through the whole process of creating a new socket then mark the socket for listening?

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn a new thread and do your alternate work in that thread while the main thread waits for clients. Once a client is connected, `accept()` gets unblocked and then you can cancel the newly spawned thread.

The code should be on the lines of:

```
while(1) {
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, do_something_else, NULL);
    consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
    pthread_cancel(thread);
}
```